# Java "Integer number too large" in Date adding calculation

Tags: java, date, integer

I have taken out irrelevant code for my question and left in what is relevant for my problem. It is stating that the Integer is too large. I have converted the current time to Milliseconds and I am trying to add a month, 2 weeks and 1 week in milliseconds to achieve the 'Date Expired'. If anyone knows how I would go about using Long instead of int? I'm confused as my Date isn't delclared as an Integer?

It is stating the error at  'dateExpired =  dateExpired + 2628000000;'.

```
public class VIP implements Serializable {
    private Date dateExpired;

    public VIP(Date dateExpired) {
        this.dateExpired = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    }


    public Date getDateExpired() {
        return dateExpired;
    }

    public void setDateExpired(String ticketType) {
       if (ticketType.equals("Gold")) {
            dateExpired =  dateExpired + 2628000000;
        } else if (ticketType.equals("Silver")) {
            dateExpired = dateExpired + 1209600000;
        } else {
            dateExpired = dateExpired + 604800000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what line is the error happening on? it should tell you if you read the stack trace.

Comment: If you are using java 8, you can check out LocalDate http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

Comment: In java a positive `int` cannot be bigger than  2,147,483,647.

Comment: Please do some research before asking questions.

Comment: You can't add a Date and an integer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the token `L` after your numbers to turn them into `long` literals:

```
public void setDateExpired(String ticketType) {
   if (ticketType.equals("Gold")) {
        dateExpired = dateExpired + 2628000000L;
    } else if (ticketType.equals("Silver")) {
        dateExpired = dateExpired + 1209600000L;
    } else {
        dateExpired = dateExpired + 604800000L;
    }
}
```

Without they L, the compiler interprets them as `int` literals, but the values are too big for the `int` type. The largest `int` value you can use is `2147483647` (though it's best not to mix types in cases like this, and just use longs throughout).

You'll also run into the issue of adding incorrect types. Either change dateExpired to be a `long` (and convert it to a `Date` later), or use this form:

```
dateExpired = new Date(dateExpired.getTime() + 604800000L)
```

Just an aside, it might help you later to document what the big numbers mean:

```
dateExpired = dateExpired + 86400000L; // one day
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. Its now stating  ' bad operand types for binary operator '+' . First type Date , Second type Long'.

Comment: I should be commenting more is right. Will save confusion later on i guess. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, now the issue is that you're adding a Date to a long. Just pick whether you want to use Date or long to represent your value (I'd go with `long`, myself), and change your code accordingly (I've added that part to my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add Date object to Long Object

use

```
public void setDateExpired(String ticketType) {
   if (ticketType.equals("Gold")) {
        dateExpired =  new Date(dateExpired.getTime() + 2628000000L);
    } else if (ticketType.equals("Silver")) {
        dateExpired = new Date(dateExpired.getTime() + 1209600000L);
    } else {
        dateExpired = new Date(dateExpired.getTime() + 604800000L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Netbeans has stopped giving out to me now! Will know this in future. Thanks again.